# The most fundamental papers in stochastic analysis

Tags: probability, reference-request, soft-question, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I have soft a question.

*What papers will be good to on start and allow me to make little step into research, without harm for reader.*

I am interested in an **stochastic analysis**. I am looking for basic, fundamental, the most often cited the works and I don't know where to start.

Comment: Research papers? Not textbooks? Are you sure this is the way you want to go?

Comment: Of course the textbooks too. I have some discern on this field, but I want to broaden this view. I asked this question because I would like to specialize in this field.

Comment: @Mateusz : You might cite some reference you are aware of in order for us to see what you really know about stochastic analysis it would then be easier to complete the missing parts. Regards

Comment: I learn mostly from http://books.google.pl/books?id=3LAntwAACAAJ, which covers from basics of probability theory to Wiener process through martingales. I fill the lacks from Billinsgley "Probability and Measure". I have read first chapter of "Stochastic Differential Equations: An Introduction with Applications". In addition, I have been learning measure theory. So I'm begginer with an huge apetite.

Comment: @ Mateusz : Ok I thought at 1st you were requesting about "stochastic analysis" ( a subject on its own in stochastic process area). Well the task is huge if you don't know the subject you want to get insight on. You can look for lectures on Malliavin Calculus (for ex Nualart as a text book), stochastic integration (look at Protter's book or G. Lowther's blog), the general theory of stochastic processes (Meyer and Dellacherie's book is a really good reference but hard to read),Brownian motion and stochastic Calculus ( Revuz and Yor's), Markov processes, Lévy Processes, Gaussian processes ...